# Adding more than one "Type" condition to Exception of Rules in New Outlook 2023

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I am trying add multiple **Types** to the Exception conditions of Rules, only one Type condition can be added. (Some other fields including Flag and Sensitivity have the same problem.)

The "Type" option simply won't show up in the drop down list if another Type condition exists. Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the by design behavior that only one type condition can be selected in the exception of rules.

To work around this, you can create multiple rules with identical condition and actions but different exception for each type. Just be sure to do not select the  "Stop processing more rules" so that all these rules can be applied to the message that match the conditions.

Below is an example for reference:
[image]

[image]

Rules will be run in order from top to down:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! However, I don't think this is working because rules are running in order one by one. In this case, they will mark mails that are not Type A (including Type B) as Read first, then Mark Mails that are not Type B (including Type A) to Read next.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Sorry that I didn't realize this when posting it. Could you share more details about your requirement? So that we can see if it can be achieved using other rules.